# Update row as copy of a row in another table without set

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to synchronize multiple tables. I want to copy a row from one table and update it to another table but I donot want to specify the column names. This is because I donot want to hard code the sql query for every table separately.

I have tried several variants, it worked with insert, but I cannot find a solution for it with Update

```
insert into t2 select * from t1 where sno=2;
```

In this code, I donot need to pass the columns names to Insert, it automatically knows the columns list. I want to achieve the same with Update where I donot want to pass the columns list inside SET portion.

Comment: What will you updating if you dont specify columns. You would need to specify what column gets what value.

Comment: I think you can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY, perhaps with the VALUEs option

Comment: I want to synchronize multiple tables. I want to copy a row from one table and update it to another table but I donot want to specify the column names. This is because I donot want to hard code the sql query for every table separately.

Comment: @Strawberry I tried insert into t1 select * from t2 where sno='2' on duplicate key update but it didnot work. Looks like a list of columns is expected after update but I donot want to hard code the column names

Comment: I think that's the point of the VALUEs option

Answer (score 0):

you always need to use SET and assign columns one by one. However you can use subquery for updating your source table using another table

```
update
  Table1 as T1
  inner join (
    select *
    from Table2 
    where ...
  ) as t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
set T1.something = t2.something
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the columns are the same, you could do:

```
delete from t2
    where exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.id = t2.id);

insert into t2
     select *
     from t1;
```

I don't see why `update` would be used to replace data (although I would still list all the columns).

If the columns are not the same, then you need to list out the ones that change.

Comment: Well, id is the Auto increment Column so if I insert the tuple, a new id will be generated. That is why I need to update the record.